# Newline on enter issue - ReactNative (Android only)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I'm trying to move my sentence into a new line when enter button is pressed in android. But even when i press the enter button the text does not break and continue as a one word.

for example;

this is what i need

**hello**

**How**

**are**

**you**

But i end up getting a text like this

**helloHowareyou**

Note that this works perfectly in ios.The issue is with android keyboard. How can i fix this?

One approach i thought was to include a `<br>` or `\n` to my text input when i press enter. How can i include one of these tags when pressing enter.

**My code**

```
                            addTextToQuestion(value) {
                                this.setState({headingState: value});
                            }

                            <TextInput
                                multiline={true}
                                blurOnSubmit={false}
                                autoFocus={true}
                                underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                                allowFontScaling={false}
                                style={styles.questionText}
                                placeholderTextColor="#C0C0C0"
                                onChangeText={this.addTextToQuestion.bind(this)}
                                placeholder={"Your question goes here"}
                            />
```

Comment: I got this char `↵` when I coded this `<TextInput multiline={true} value={this.props.email} onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}/>` and console the output. If you also get this char you can replace it with newline char

Comment: what do you mean you get char ↵ ? when i console the enter button , all it shows is a empty space

Comment: after setting `multiline` prop and logging entered text `onChangeText` I got `↵ ` character between text (wherever I pressed enter )